# How to show 4 not equal to 6 only using Peano's Postulates?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came up with this question- how would you show 4 not equal to 6 (or m not equal to m+n ( n not 0)), using only Peano's Postulates?

I can see a number of things go wrong- for instance the Principle of Mathematical Induction seems to fail. Also possibly 0 seems to be in the image of the successor function in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $4 = 6$, where $4 = S(S(S(S(0))))$ and $6 = S(S(S(S(S(S(0))))))$. One of the Peano axioms states that the successor function $S$ is injective. So if $S(3) = 4 = 6 = S(5)$, then $3 = 5$. Similarly, $S(2) = 3 = 5 = S(4) \implies 2 = 4$. Doing this two more times, you arrive at $0 = 2 = S(S(0))$. But another of the Peano axioms states that there is not integer $n$ such that $S(n) = 0$, so this is a contradiction.

Comment: any way to prove it in general case? where n = n+m (m not 0)

Comment: @Alex77 induction on $n$. Prove that $K:=\{n\in\omega\mid n\neq n+m\}$ contains $0$ and satisfies $n\in K\rightarrow S(n)\in K$. This for $m\neq0$.

Comment: I think I solved it by PMI: assume U the set where n is a Natural number where the following statement is false n= n+m for any m (m not 0). Then

Comment: thats exactly it, thanks again :)  :)